# How to merge multiple CSV without coulmn name as headers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 7 CSVs and I want to merge them based on the id, below is the illustrated example:

CSV1:

```
101, A, B, C, D               
102, A, B, C, D
```

CSV2:

```
101, E, F
102, E, F
```

CSV3:

```
101, J, K, L
102, J, K, L
```

Consolidated CSV which I require:

```
101, A, B, C, D, E, F, J, K, L
102, A, B, C, D, E, F, J, K, L
```

The CSV doesn't have column name or headers.

I tried using pandas merge and concat but that doesn't seem to work as it is multiplying the fields. Please help.

Comment: Use the 'axis=1' parameter with pd.concat() to create wide tables:  `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that all files are inside directory.

```
import pathlib, pandas as pd

path = pathlib.Path("path to directory")

conslidated_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file_,header=None).set_index(0) for file_ in path.iterdir()],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for idx, df in enumerate(dataframes):
   if idx == 0:
       merged_df = dataframe[1] #df2
   merge_total = pd.merge(df, merged_df, how="inner", on="id")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we can do it step by step

Assumption: you have all the csv files in a folder.

#### Step 1. Getting the path of all csv files

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
csv_folder='csvs/'
df_list=list(filter(lambda x:x.lower().endswith('.csv'),os.listdir(csv_folder)))
```

Sample output looks like:

```
['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']
```

#### Step 2: read all csv and concatenate them

```py
combined_df=pd.DataFrame()

for df_name in df_list:
    df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(csv_folder,df_name),header=None,index_col=0)
    combined_df=pd.concat([combined_df,df],axis=1)
```

#### Final df looks like

```
      1   2   3   4   1   2   1   2   3
0                                      
101   A   B   C   D   E   F   J   K   L
102   A   B   C   D   E   F   J   K   L
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, but when I implemented this:raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (52205, 6), indices imply (52175, 6)

Comment: I think it's because of the index issue. If duplicate index is present, this error can happen. Can you add a `print(df_name)` in the loop and share the CSV which is creating the error.

Comment: it is throwing error while reading the second file, pfb the data I have and I need:-  file1-101, Y, 1999-07-01 00:00:00.0,
file2-101, 00000004, 2004-01-01 00:00:00.0, 

final_file - 101, Y, 1999-07-01 00:00:00.0, 00000004, 2004-01-01 00:00:00.0,

Comment: It doesn't throw any error when I try to run it and giving the same as final_file. can you just read the file1 and file2 separately using `pd.read_csv('filepath')` and make sure there is no error happening in csv formatting?